# Popular language tags with almost same number of questions

Tags: discussion, questions

I've searched for the following tags and got a similiar number of questions:

- [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java): 698,494 questions
- [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23): 686,657 questions
- [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript): 680,954 questions

Is this just some kind of odd coincidence?

Comment: ... Yes, those are popular languages. What's your point?

Comment: No, we do that on purpose by padding [java] with thousands of questions about string equality. ;)

Comment: Even weirder: when you add all those numbers together, you get the same result no matter which number you add first!

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

If you really think about it, though, a 6,000/12,000/18,000 question difference is quite large.

I get what you're saying, though: on that scale, it's a relatively small difference, since we're talking about ***hundreds*** of thousands of questions.

They've all been in existence for the entirety of Stack Overflow (~6 years) and have grown at about the same rate due to their popularity, so it makes sense that there would be a "similar" number of questions.

Comment: That's the absolute amount but there are only 1.7 % more java than c# questions and only 0.8 % less javascript than c# questions.

Comment: If you check questions with 2 out of these 3 tags, those numbers are near to these differences. Would that mean that if you *exclude* double-tags, you'd get the **same** numbers for all? Coincidence? I think not. (Dons tin foil hat, *again*.)

Comment: @Jongware Somehow, I think (or rather, hope) that the cross tagging between C#, Java, and JavaScript would be minimal.

Comment: @Jongware Good point about that, though: the differences *are* very close to the cross tag numbers.

Comment: Double-tagging? [Never underestimate first time users.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494293/javascript-phone-number-display-from-time-zone)

Comment: @Jongware Yes, that would be the "hope" part there.